# How to capture multiple values for CLI option using typer lib?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, typer

Building CLI tool for exchange rate using Python Typer library

```
$./exchangerates fetchcommand --start 2021-09-01 --end 2021-09-02 --base USD --symbol EUR
CAD
```

How to capture multiple values for `--symbol` (space separated), count is not fixed as mentioned in above example.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation of `argparse`?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a bunch for suggesting.  I tried using the argparse lib instead typer It worked out well!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.